# make a request using REST_CLIENT, equivalent to a curl request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, httpclient, rest-client

I am trying to make this curl request using rest_client, and I keep getting it wrong. How can I do it?

curl request: it is working well and returning an access token from yahoo.

```
curl -u "<consumer_key>:<consumer_secret>" -d "grant_type=authorization_code&code=<code>&redirect_uri=<redirect_uri>" https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/get_token
```

the rest_client request that I am trying to make work is:

```
# get token
  yahoo_url = "https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/get_token/"
  response = RestClient::Request.new(
      :method => :get,
      :url => yahoo_url,
      :client_id => $consumer_id,
      :client_secret => $consumer_secret,
      :headers => { :accept => :json,:content_type => :json},
      :params => {'grant_type' => 'authorization_code', 'code' => code, 'redirect_uri' => $yahoo_redirect_url}
  ).execute
  results = JSON.parse(response.to_str)
  puts "RESULTS: #{results}"
```

or this one:

```
response = RestClient.get 'https://dj0yJmk9Q1RKU2xclient_id:be49966a23db7_client_secretb@api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/get_token', {:params => {'grant_type' => 'authorization_code', 'code' => code, 'redirect_uri' => $yahoo_redirect_url}}
```

Any help or suggestions or even a better too that can work will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a long shot but I think you are not passing the user name and password correctly. I would see passing them as parameters in Request.new(options, user, password) as indicated here https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client#usage-activeresource-style

Comment: I have tried your way, and many others. Its like I am missing something while passing the parameters like grant_type, code, redirect_uri..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request must be a HTTP POST instead of a HTTP GET and pass the parameters as in:

```
# POST or PUT with a hash sends parameters as a urlencoded form body
# RestClient.post 'http://example.com/resource', :param1 => 'one'
```

so:

```
response = RestClient.post 'https://dj0yJmk9Q1RKU2xclient_id:be49966a23db7_client_secretb@api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/get_token', :grant_type => 'authorization_code', :code => code, :redirect_uri => $yahoo_redirect_url
```

Comment: am I passing the parameters well?